# what formular can i use to get 3 STATUSES OF output of Late, ontime and early in text from comparing dates in SHAREPOINT 2007

Tags: if-statement, sharepoint-2007, datediff

I am trying to determine 3 statuses comparing a Due date to a Completed Date with an output of On Time, Late and Early, I can get the Late and Early to work perfectly but it sees On Time results as Late.

HERE IS THE FORMULAR IM USING AT THE MOMENT, AND ITS NOT WORKING

=IF([FeasibilityTracker_Date Due]<=[FeasibilityTracker_Date Delivered],"Ontime","Early","LATE")

Does anyone have ideas on how to fix this?